# CSS Sub-Menu being displayed google maps script

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, tags

My CSS nav menu works somewhat but comes behind the google map I have set up.  It is in a DIV tag but I have made it so that it comes overtop of the main DIV tag below it but the google map script I am using overlay on top to he nav map.

I have tried to position the menu div so it is suppose to be over the main body div but the script for the google maps still overlaps the div menu CSS.  Any clues on how to fix this please?

[JSFIDDLE code here](https://jsfiddle.net/8n4g92ej/1/)

```
.nav-bar ul li:hover, #mega-menu{
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

.inner-mega-menu{
  width: 24%;
  float: top;
  margin-right: 1%;
}

.inner-mega-menu p{
  padding: 10px 0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.inner-mega-menu:last-child{
  margin-right: 0%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should work using an axe selector and also adding a higher z-index like:

```
.nav-bar ul li:hover > .mega-menu{
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 2;   
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lx98qgv1/